# Error while consuming post method from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is my whole code of web api method which is creating team and i am consuming this method in client. I have tested this post method via /api/Team/insertTeam and it's adding new team in database but giving error while cunsuming with httpclient/

```
    [HttpPost]
            [Route("insertTeam")]
            public int insertTeam(Team team)
            {
                int teamid = -1;
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Team", con))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO team(Score, wideball, Noball, name, wickets, overs) VALUES(@score, @wideball, @noball, @name, @wickets, @overs); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", team.Score);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wideball", team.Wideball);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noball", team.Noball);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", team.Name);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wickets", team.Wickets);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@overs", team.Overs);
    
                            teamid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n----------Error-----------\n");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                return teamid;
            }
```

Code of client project

```
    private void AddTeam()
                            {
                                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44382/api/Team");
                                //Adding teams
                                Team team1 = new Team
                                {
                                    Name = tbteam1.Text,
                                    Score = 0,
                                    Wideball = 0,
                                    Noball = 0,
                                    Wickets = 0,
                                    Overs = 0,
                                };
                                Team team2 = new Team
                                {
                                    Name = tbteam2.Text,
                                    Score = 0,
                                    Wideball = 0,
                                    Noball = 0,
                                    Wickets = 0,
                                    Overs = 0,
                                };
    
    
                                MediaTypeFormatter[] formatter = new MediaTypeFormatter[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() };
                                HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Team>(team1, formatter[0]);
                                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/insertTeam", content).Result;
    
    }
```

Error at postAsync method in client code

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Client.team.AddTeam() in K:\LiveScoreSystemWebApi\Client\team.aspx.cs:line 259
   at Client.team.GoBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in K:\LiveScoreSystemWebApi\Client\team.aspx.cs:line 51

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Inner Exception 3:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Inner Exception 4:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: The error is clear, even though the code isn't, and contains several bugs. The HTTP connection was closed abruptly. As for the code a) it looks like there's no error handling. What you posted looks like the event written to the Windows Event log when an application crashes. You need to add proper error handling and logging. b) You're using `.Result` with an asynchronous method. Don't do that. use `async/await`. Change the method's signature to `async Task AddTeam()`. c) the code creates a new HttpClient instance on every call. HttpClient is meant to be reused though, even from multiple threads

Comment: Did the *server* crash perhaps, before it had a chance to respond or even send a 500 error?

Comment: works in postman but not in client

Comment: Is there any other solution??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public  async Task PostData
{   
                                var team1 = new Team
                                {
                                    Name = tbteam1.Text,
                                    Score = 0,
                                    Wideball = 0,
                                    Noball = 0,
                                    Wickets = 0,
                                    Overs = 0,
                                };
                             

 using var client = new HttpClient();
 client.BaseAddress = new  Uri("http://localhost:44382/api/Team");
 var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
var stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(team1);
contentData = new StringContent(stringData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/insertTeam", contentData);
.....
}
```

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll      this error is also there

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling your addteam metod. pls?

Comment: protected void GoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddTeamAsync();
            Response.Redirect("toss.aspx");
        }

Answer (score 0):

just change the baseaddress https from http..!!

Comment: This answer was flagged to moderators as low quality. I think it's OK but maybe you could add some more detail about why https works rather than http to help out future readers.